# Javascript - Trying to make it wait

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, So I'm trying to have this code display text at different intervals in a specific div. "text1" appears in the div normally but after a few secs the page loads everything disappears and the text is visible but on a blank page.

Could someone help me so text2 and text3 appear in the div with the rest of the content.

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function typeText1()
    {
        document.write('<p style="color:blue;">text1</p>');
        setTimeout( "typeText2();", 1000);
    }
    function typeText2()
    {
        document.write('<p style="color:blue;">text2</p>');
        setTimeout( "typeText3();", 3000);
    }
    function typeText3()
    {
        document.write('<p style="color:blue;">text3</p>');
    }
    typeText1();
    </script>
```

Comment: Don't use document.write, you should be appending the HTML to the desired location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are using `document.write`. It rewrites over the entire document. Use methods like `appendChild` or `replaceChild` or even `.innerHTML`.

For succinctness I'll just use innerHTML as an example:

```
<div id="thing"></div>

<script>
(function() {
 var thing = document.getElementById('thing');

 function typeText1() { thing.innerHTML = '<p>text1</p>'; setTimeout( typeText2, 1000 ); }
 function typeText2() { thing.innerHTML = '<p>text2</p>'; setTimeout( typeText3, 1000 ); }
 function typeText3() { thing.innerHTML = '<p>text3</p>'; }

 typeText1();

})();
</script>
```

Edit #2:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    * { margin:0; padding:0; }
.one { color:red; }
.two { color:blue; }
.three { color:yellow; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="thing"></p>

<script>
(function() {
 var thing = document.getElementById('thing');

 function typeText1() { thing.innerHTML+= 'text1'; thing.className+= ' one'; setTimeout( typeText2, 1000 ); }
 function typeText2() { thing.innerHTML+= '<br>text2'; thing.className+= ' two'; setTimeout( typeText3, 1000 ); }
 function typeText3() { thing.innerHTML+= '<br>text3'; thing.className+= ' three'; }

 typeText1();

})();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @meder No need to recreate the P element each time, since only the P content changes.

Comment: I am well aware of that and would realistically do something more efficient, however I'm just giving him ideas and examples of embedding html when assigning to `innerHTML`...

Comment: This works but how can I change it to not overwrite text1, but rather write the next text on the line?

Comment: Create a paragraph, give it an id, reference it, and alter its innerHTML to do `innerHTML+= '<br>text2';`

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to get such effects, you might be better of looking into a javascript framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.org). They provide alot of easy functions for exactly these things.

Comment: This answer does not address `document.write` nor the delaying, and recommends jQuery without even examples thus I downvote.

Answer (score -2):

Simple example using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("body")
        .append("<p style='color:blue;'>text1</p>")
        .delay(1000)
        .append("<p style='color:blue;'>text2</p>")
        .delay(1000)
        .append("<p style='color:blue;'>text3</p>");
});
```

If you have to do this lots of times then it might be better to set up a loop. Equally, if you have a lot of content whose appearance you want to delay then it might be better to put it in the HTML, hide it when the page loads, then use Javascript to display it.

Comment: this is wrong, it won't work as expected, since the delay function only works on jquery's animation stuff (i.e. not append)